# Google authentication for non-touch device

Tags: google-oauth

When using an android tv device without google services, I'm having some trouble to get oauth2 working nicely. The embedded browser is not supported so I redirect the user to google chrome that I installed separately. That works when I connect with a mouse but because the user only has a remote control (no touch), it is impossible to select the fields to enter user/pass.
It seems the web page does not have the focus and with the remote it is not possible.

Anyone know a browser that is non-touch friendly and still allowed by Google?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use OAuth for limited input devices. See https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ForDevices.

Comment: Thank you fo rthe suggestion would indeed be a good alternative. Unfortunately I want to connect to google photos which is not in the supported scopes so I'm not allowed to use this.